# How to update mysql with python where fields and entries are from a dictionary?

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

I am trying to create a re-usable mysql statement for updating from a dictionary where the keys are the database fields and the data to go into that field is the value associated with it in the dictionary.  This was easy when creating a function for inserting into mysql because it just involved two lists.  Now, I need to break apart the lists.

Here is what I have to work with.

```
fields = self.dictionary.keys()
vals = self.dictionary.values()

stmt = "UPDATE TABLE table_name SET %s = '%s'" %(.join(fields), .join(vals))"
```

This outputs a statement like:

```
UPDATE TABLE table_name SET column1, column2 = ('value1','value2')
```

I need it to output to standard format for updating a table like:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column1=value1, column2=value2
```

Answer (score 21):

You don't want to be putting literal values in using string interpolation - SQL injection attacks are **not a Good Thing(tm)**. Instead, you use the placeholder syntax relevant for your database (I think MySQL's is '%s').

*Note: I'm using `.format` here, change to use % if you want, but escape any %'s*

```
d = {'col1': 'val1', 'col2': 'val2'}
sql = 'UPDATE table SET {}'.format(', '.join('{}=%s'.format(k) for k in d))
print sql
# 'UPDATE table SET col2=%s, col1=%s'
```

Assuming `cur` is a DB cursor the correct way to perform the query is:

```
cur.execute(sql, d.values())
```

This works because although the ordering of a dictionary is effectively arbitrary order, the order of keys/values of a dict will be consistent such that `dict(zip(d.keys(), d.values())) == d`.

Comment: In python3 you should use:
cur.execute(sql, list(d.values()))

Answer (score 1):

how about trying

```
stmt = "UPDATE TABLE table_name SET "
for k,v in di.items():
    stmt += "%s = %s, " %(k,v)

stmt = stmt[-2:]
```

Comment: This implementation is prone to SQL injection attacks. If a user is able to set the values of the dictionary they can execute arbitrary SQL statements. You need to use proper escaping techniques.

Answer (score 0):

```
def dict2sql(table,dt,cond):
    return 'UPDATE `{}` SET {} WHERE {}'.format(table,', '.join('{}="{}"'.format(k,v) for k, v in dt.items()),cond)

d = {'col1': 'val1', 'col2': 'val2'}
print(dict2sql("table", d, "name=1"))
```

Comment: This implementation is prone to SQL injection attacks. If a user is able to set the values of the dictionary they can execute arbitrary SQL statements. You need to use proper escaping techniques.