# Creating Oracle Update Statements from Python Dictionary

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I am have a dictionary in my python script that contains data as column_name:value and from this I want to create update statement. I'm using python 3.3 and cx-oracle
I found this answer: [How to update mysql with python where fields and entries are from a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517106/how-to-update-mysql-with-python-where-fields-and-entries-are-from-a-dictionary)

and have used it as:

```
 SQL = 'UPDATE scheme SET {}'.format(', '.join('{}=%s'.format(k) for k in schemes_dict))
cursor.execute(SQL, schemes_dict.values())
```

but it errors with:

```
TypeError: expecting a dictionary, sequence or keyword args
```

I've been googling and reading up but I can't find a way of making it work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/cursor.html) it seems that you're calling:

```
Cursor.execute(statement[, parameters], **keywordParameters)
```

as in the other answer, you could match by position with

```
cursor.execute(SQL, *list(schemes_dict.values()))
```

or maybe, from the error message, a simple sequence is OK:

```
cursor.execute(SQL, list(schemes_dict.values()))
```

(i've just added `list(...)` for python 3 - see below)

but that relies on the order of the two iterations being the same (which is likely true in this case with cpython, but not something you should be trusting in general).  it seems to me that it would be better to use named bindings (using `:name` instead of `%s`):

```
SQL = 'UPDATE scheme SET {}'.format(', '.join('{}=:{}'.format(k, k) for k in schemes_dict))
cursor.execute(SQL, **schemes_dict)
```

where `**` is like having `name1=value1, name2=value2, ...` from the dict.

or maybe

```
cursor.execute(SQL, schemes_dict)   # using the new SQL above
```

(the alternatives are because the error message seems to suggest that sequences and dicts would also work).

the `list(...)` is needed because in python 3 `dict.values()` returns some kind of generator thing (technically, an "iterable view") - [see here](http://blog.labix.org/2008/06/27/watch-out-for-listdictkeys-in-python-3).

Comment: thanks for this but I'm still struggling, when I use cursor.execute(SQL, **schemes_dict) I get cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number. Is there a way to get the actual statement that is being sent to the DB? I tried adding print(cursor.statement) but its falling over before it gets there

Comment: i've changed the answer.  for named bind it's a different SQL syntax, but also try the other suggestions.